# Difference between Android Monitor Method trace and Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, ddms, android-traceview

I profiled the same app for cpu time using both Android Device Monitor (method profiling) and Android Monitor (method profiling), however, I get different results. Any ideas on how they are different in their underlying working?

1) Android Device Monitor 
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

2) Android Monitors
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html

As for as I observe,d there is no option in Android Monitors (2) to select either trace-based or sampling-based profiling. Moreover, there is no option for changing the buffer size of method trace so only a few seconds of data can be collected.

I'm curious if one is more or less accurate than the other.

Comment: If you use sample based profiling in Andorid Device Monitor it is less accurate than method tracing, especially when method execution time is small, but significantly faster. Do you experience different results between method tracing in Android Device Monitor and Andorid Monitor?